# A Dark Room didn't autosave?

Tags: a-dark-room

After getting pretty far into The Dusty Path on A Dark Room yesterday, I was incredibly disappointed upon opening the game today on the same computer and finding that all my progress had vanished!!! Can I not close the game without losing my progress? I'd rather not have to leave it open for days on end while I beat it.

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Vemonous' comment

Comment: Only the title of the proposed duplicate seems relevant. This question appears distinct.

Comment: Agreeing with RoddyoftheFrozenPeas. That linked question is more like asking if there is autosave; this asker knows that there is autosave, but accusing that autosave did not work for the asker, thus asking for alternate method to save the game, I think.

Answer (score 1):

The game is saved when you stoke the fire.  I've never had this problem before with the game (I play on IOS), so I'm sorry if I'm not much help.  I would assume that you haven't been manually saving.

Comment: I don't know about mobile, but on PC stoking the fire does nothing than the original mechanic of heating up the room.

Answer (score 1):

The game automatically saves every one minute, and you will see the words "game saved" in the top right corner of your screen. If you are playing in incognito mode, private mode, or any mode that doesn't save cookies, the the game will not save.

If you do want to play on incognito/private mode, you can click save, then export, to get the save code. Copy the code and paste it somewhere else, then when you want to play again, copy the code and go to save, then import. That method also works to transfer your game from different devices.

Answer (score 0):

It autosaves for me when I stoke the fire on a PC. The other way that I know is to click the save button on the bottom of the screen and pasting it into a Google docs.

Comment: Hi Juju, can you explain what "stoke the fire" means? And pasting what into Google Docs?

Answer (score 0):

There are different online versions to the game. Each of them save cookies separately. Try to backtrack to where you originally clicked on a link to the game, and your old save will be there.